# Is <%= yield %> the Rails equivalent of MVC3's RenderContent()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I'm following the Ruby of Rails [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), and I see this code in the layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body style="background: #EEEEEE;">

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Coming from an MVC3 background, is this the equivalent to the RenderContent() method one would invoke from the _layout.cshtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality is about the same in that context, yes. However, `yield` in general is a keyword in the ruby language, concerning blocks. You can find more information here: [ruby blocks](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm).

Building on that, you are able to provide content for different parts, using `content_for(:something)` and `yield :something` (the `yield` passes `:something` to the layout engine, the layout engine fills in the content for it).